# why does almost all of this file get omitted in the output?

Tags: css, sass

using indentation based sass I'm having a specific css rule I'm trying to generate be silently omitted. No error message, and before I converted it to indentation format, it was working. I tried the following code in https://www.sassmeister.com/ and the behavior is the same

```
button.btn-danger
  background-image:none
button
  border: 1px inset
  .danger
    background-image:none
  .btn
    background-image:none
  &.btn
    background-image:none
  &:hover
    font: 10px
button.btndanger
  backgroundimage:none
```

none of the code involving a class name with `danger` in it are in the output:

```
button {
  border: 1px inset;
}
button:hover {
  font: 10px;
}
```

my original:

```
button
  .btn-danger
    background-image:none
```

is this a bug in sass, am I doing something wrong with the syntax, or is there something illegal about my css selectors?

(edit) additional info: 
both of these work (even on 3.3.14)

```sass
button.btn-danger
  :background-image none

button
  &.btn-danger
    :background-image none
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong compiler, you need to use libSass to compile, take a look at the [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/5ac7a72306d9e4e13c0009cc7eecad04)

SASS

```css
// ----
// libsass (v3.5.0.beta.2)
// ----

button.btn-danger
  background-image:none

button
  border: 1px inset
  .danger
    background-image:none
  .btn
    background-image:none
  &.btn
    background-image:none
  &:hover
    font: 10px

button.btndanger
  backgroundimage:none
```

OUTPUT

```css
button.btn-danger {
  background-image: none;
}

button {
  border: 1px inset;
}

button .danger {
  background-image: none;
}

button .btn {
  background-image: none;
}

button.btn {
  background-image: none;
}

button:hover {
  font: 10px;
}

button.btndanger {
  backgroundimage: none;
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on why there are different compilers and perhaps why a compiler that seems to understand the syntax isn't intended to comprehend it? is that site horribly outdated or something?

Comment: so I checked and it seems I'm using node-sass@3.13.0

Comment: @Maslow see the link now please. and AFAIK, this complier works with files `.sass` (old syntax) and the others work with `.scss` (new syntax)

Comment: I've been to the link, however it tells me nothing about what I can do to fix this. libSass says it requires a wrapper. I'm using the wrapper `node-sass@3.13.0`. I'm not having much luck figuring out why `npm view node-sass` which says it is using `libsass 3.5.0.beta.2` doesn't produce the same results.

Comment: updated to `node-sass@4.52` still the original does not result in css being generated.